# using regex to grab information from an article

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'm using regex and beautiful soup to grab information from an article. I currently can't seem to get exactly what I need from the output. For the date, I only need to get the first instance that is returned in the list. I tried iterating through the list but haven't had much luck yet. For the author, I want to cut out the a href tags and just get who it's by rather than the whole returned string. I tried a loop and changing some regex calls, but haven't been able to narrow it down. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Below is the relevant code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import *

url: http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/02/26/us-afghanistan-usa-militants-idUSBREA1O1SV20140226

# Parse HTML of article, aka making soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

# Write the article author to the file    
regex = '<p class="byline">(.+?)</p>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
byline = re.findall(pattern,str(soup))
txt.write("Author: " + str(byline) + '\n' + '\n')

# Write the article date to the file    
regex = '<span class="timestamp">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
byline = re.findall(pattern,str(soup))
txt.write("Date: " + str(byline) + '\n' + '\n')
```

Comment: You don't need regex at all, use BeautifulSoup! and the date is in the 8 last characters of the url.

Comment: Can you provide an example for how you would grab the author using bs4? I've read the beautiful soup documentation and their methods weren't producing the desired output. Although I'm new to python so it was likely a misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to grab exactly what you need using almost the same approach you described, just without the regex.  Since you know the characteristics of the tags your interested in, you can search for them directly using bs4's `find`

```
#make some soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

#extract byline and date text from their respective tags
try:
    byline=soup.find("p", {'class':'byline'}).text
    date=soup.find("span", {'class':'timestamp'}).text
except:
    print 'byline missing!'
```

**UPDATED**:
if you wrap the whole thing in a `try/except` structure, you can address situations where the byline is missing and define some alternative action that should occur.

Comment: You sir are a great man. I had been struggling with this for a while. Thank you for taking the time to help a beginner out.

Comment: If the byline does not exist, it breaks the code. Is there a way to check if the statement is true? Or have it return nothing and continue without breaking?